# Is it possible to use Layout instead of Drawable for DividerItemDecoration?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I want to use custom separator between horizontally scrolled items in `RecyclerView`. I can use icon as `Drawable` but this icon filled whole space as separator and appeared stretched. I made custom `RelativeLayout` where I centered this separator as `ImageView` and added custom padding to it. I don't want to add this separator (arrow) to the vertical center of `Layout` but slightly below center. It's custom icon with custom padding.

That's being said I want to somehow add this separator into `DividerItemDecoration`, but it accepts only `Drawable`.

UPDATE:

I tried to inflate this custom layout and convert it to Drawable.
Problem is that inflated layout has 0 width and height.

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(app).inflate(R.layout.separator, null)
val bitmapDecoration = view?.let { viewToBitmap(it, it.width, it.height) }
val drawableDecoration = BitmapDrawable(app.resources, bitmapDecoration)
itemDecoration.setDrawable(drawableDecoration)
```

Example of my separator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_black_short"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image (Custom divider between recyclerview items):

[image]

If I use only divider icon as `Drawable` and I add it to `DividerItemDecoration` it looks like this(it will stretch drawable to fill parent):

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture of what you actually need

Comment: You can create own class inheriting from `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration()`

Comment: I've created own class but I dont know how to use Layout instead of Drawable, because every method is using Rect there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

1. Create the following class:

   ```
   public class HorizontalDrawableDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
       private final int paddingTopPx, paddingBottomPx, paddingLeftPx, paddingRightPx;
       private final Drawable drawable;
       private Rect bounds;

       public HorizontalDrawableDecoration(Context context,
                                       @DrawableRes int drawableId,
                                       @DimenRes int paddingTop, @DimenRes int paddingBottom,
                                       @DimenRes int paddingLeft, @DimenRes int paddingRight ) {
           this.paddingTopPx = getDimenPx(context, paddingTop);
           this.paddingBottomPx = getDimenPx(context, paddingBottom);
           this.paddingLeftPx = getDimenPx(context, paddingLeft);
           this.paddingRightPx = getDimenPx(context, paddingRight);
           this.drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
           bounds = new Rect();
       }

       @Override
       public void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
           super.onDraw(canvas, parent, state);
           int top = Math.round((parent.getHeight() + paddingTopPx + paddingBottomPx - drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2f);
           int bottom = top + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
           int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
           for (int i=0; i< childCount; i++) {
               View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
               parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, bounds);
               final int right = bounds.right + Math.round(child.getTranslationX()) - paddingRightPx;
               final int left = right - drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
               drawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom );
               drawable.draw(canvas);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, @NonNull View view, @NonNull RecyclerView parent, @NonNull RecyclerView.State state) {
           super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
           if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == state.getItemCount() - 1) {
               outRect.setEmpty();
           } else {
               outRect.set(0,0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + paddingLeftPx + paddingRightPx, 0);
           }
       }

       private int getDimenPx(Context context, @DimenRes int dimenId) {
           return (context == null || dimenId == 0)? 0: context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimenId);
       }
   }
   ```
2. New the HorizontalDrawableDecoration and add it to your RecyclerView.

   ```
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDrawableDecoration(
           this, R.drawable.arrow_black_short, R.dimen.dp4, 0, R.dimen.dp8, R.dimen.dp8));
   ```
3. One more thing,add dimens to dimens.xml file in res/values:

   ```
   <dimen name="dp8">8dp</dimen>
   <dimen name="dp4">4dp</dimen>
   ```

Comment: This worked but I cant set custom padding now. It is ignored for some reason inside getItemOffsets. There I want to set padding start and end

Comment: Where do you want padding,the arrows?

Comment: Yes, arrow separator should have padding 8dp on a left and right side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a class that draws the divide item decoration instead of using a view or layout. [This article](https://proandroiddev.com/itemdecoration-in-android-e18a0692d848) goes into more detail about why you want to go this route and also has an example to work off of.

As of api 25 you can also use this.

```
var decoration: DividerItemDecoration =  DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), VERTICAL)
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(decoration)
```

I hope this helps you get on the right track of what your wanting to accomplish.